# Live Body Preservation.....A way to live for many centuries?

Tags: humans, life, preservation

I was thinking that if there was a machine which preserved live human body without aging would that be a way/solution to live for many centuries?

ex- A person at age 40 sleeps in that machine & wakes up after 60 years. Lives for more 30 years & again goes to sleep. Even though he has lived for 130 odd years his age will be 70 years.

---

Will this help solve or at least reduce the depleting resources problem we are facing?

After many years from now, could this become a reality? I think so because the human population is growing rapidly.

Could this be a way so that everyone could live equally & get equal opportunities if organized properly?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE. If you have a moment please take the tour and visit the help center to learn more. Have fun!

Comment: Mohit, please read our help section on what are good questions here. You are asking too many questions and some of theme sound really opinion based. We do not debate on opinion, we try to decide based on objective measurables.

Comment: Also, please try to match the title you give to the question with the actual content of the question.

Comment: @BladeWraith In case you haven't come across a somewhat hidden feature: have a look at [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000). You can write something like `[tour]` and `[help]` and it will automatically link to the corresponding resources on the site you are currently writing the comment on. The feature is [a bit hidden](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6116/28789) but immensely useful when writing comments because it allows linking to the chat, meta, tour, help center,... with sometimes less characters

Comment: @Secespitus, Awesome, i was wondering how to do that, but decided to just put it up and be neighborly, Cheers

Comment: I think this question is of average quality on WB if you can explain why you think this would help us with depleting resources and drop the last 2 questions since they are nothing but wild speculation, something which is often called "opinion based." Also, you are asking how to get equality of outcome and equality of opportunity simultaneously which makes no sense

Comment: Hello, *Mohit Kulkarni*, and welcome to Worldbuilding.  Please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about the way the site works.  Have a nice day!

Comment: This question has appeared in the VTR queue, but it has not yet been updated.  The intent of the question is good, but the Stack Exchange model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  Mohit, I hope you will review the advice provided by earlier posters.  As mentioned, the problem with your current question is this: the answers are "yes, maybe, maybe, maybe."  It will help if you understand Stack Exchange is a Question & Answer service, [not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  Thanks!

Comment: Downvoted because (as stated) the question contains a fundamental logical flaw.  The person has only lived 70 years, not 130, albeit those 70 years were at different times.  Also see for instance Heinlein's "The Door Into Summer" (1956) for one (of a great many) explorations of the topic.

Answer (score 5):

You're basically talking about Cryogenics, its an actively researched field at the moment. maybe your wanting it without the freezing part, but there are several other questions about cryogenics around that i would just be copying so i'll just answer your questions instead

**Will it help reduce resource usuage**... No, not only would it take some of those depleting resources to build the machines, but would likely take a lot of power and possibly other things to run them, using up yet more resources. then you'd have all the people that need to run the facility where it takes place, taking up more, and then the facility buildings themselves all around the world, each requiring resources to maintain let alone the infrastructure beyond these points

**Will it be possible in the future**... possibly, its being researched for making extra planetary trips more realistic, why support a generational spaceship for a few hundred years to reach another planet when you could have them sleep for that time instead.

**Could this allow Equality**

Most definitely not, this sort of thing wold be heavily abused for profiteering, who makes them and maintains them? someone has to pay for it, the machines would probably be expensive to build and run so it would be an expensive treatment therefore only the wealthy would be able to afford it, remember if you're asleep for even 10 years, thats 10 years where you are not working and therefore not earning money, so unless you you own a business that can be run by other parties while you sleep, then you won't be able to afford to do this

Comment: "if you're asleep for even 10 years, thats 10 years where you are not working and therefore not earning money". Well, if you are rich enough, you could pay some dudes to handle your money while you sleep. As long as the profit are higher than inflation, you could wake up **richer** than before. Sure, if you where active during 10 years you could make more money than with some stock market investment, but from your point of view, you fall asleep with 10 million $ and wake up with 25

Comment: @Kepotx, That was my point that only the wealthy could afford to do it, perhaps i didn't word it quite right, i'll add a bit to the end to clarify my original point